# Video play in landscape although i recorded in portrait

Tags: android, recording, portrait

As title says i have this code to prepare my recorder:

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();

    Camera.Parameters p = myCamera.getParameters();

    p.set("orientation", "landscape");
    p.set("rotation", 90);
    myCamera.setParameters(p);

    myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/rec/temp/video_" + String.valueOf(videoCount) + ".mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(12500); // Set max duration 11 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(7000000); // Set max file size 7M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());


    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

And i have in my surface view:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
            int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {

            myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
```

That is the only two places where camera is used(rotation)...
And when recording it's fine everything is in portrait, but when i play back that video it's landscape. Can anyone tell me why and how i can fix this?

Comment: have you tried setting the camera to portrait instead of landscape like you do here "p.set("orientation", "landscape");"

Answer (score 2):

Use setOrientationHint(int degrees) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint(int)

mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90); (90 for back facing camera, 270 for front facing camera)
Call this before mediaRecorder.prepare();

Comment: But that just set composition matrix to selected value, and most of the players ignore that value.